Signed Fixed Point Numbers Rounding Towards Zero
I need an idea on how to round a signed fixed point number in format a.b (a and b are bits for integer and fraction part) towards zero to 3 digits after the radix.
So, I had an idea to shift the fraction part to 10 bits (if it has) so 3-digit decimal would fit there. Also, I tried just rounding the decimal representation but it doesn't not really works.
For example, for this test:
12.13 0xb34cf356 + 0x95247d00
the result is 001110001011 (907 is the integer part) and 1000001010110 (0.509 is the fraction part 'cause I cut 3 last bits). We should round towards zero, the right answer is 907.510.
Just need an idea on how to do it right.

Which programming language are you using? The programming language might already have relevant functions which do the rounding for you.
